# Fill cshtml at runtime with data from indexeddb

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, view, indexeddb

I have a viewmodel saved in an indexedDB in the browser, I have the html page cached. example (only part of the view) below, the model saved in the indexeddb is the InspectionUpsertViewModel:

```
@using Common.OM
@using ACA.OM.Tag_M
@model ACA.WebERP.Models.Inspection_M.InspectionUpsertViewModel
<div class="content">
    <div class="block block-rounded block-bordered">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-alt">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a id="step1" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-step-1">@ACA.Translations.Measurement.Step1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-step-2">@ACA.Translations.Measurement.Step2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a id="step3" class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-step-3">@ACA.Translations.Measurement.Step3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="subTypeChangeAlert" style="display:none;">
                @ACA.Translations.Measurement.AlertSubTypeChange
            </div>
            <h4>@ACA.Translations.Inspection.InspectionNr @Model.Inspection.Nr</h4>
        </div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "step1-form" }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Inspection.Id)
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-step-1" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="block-content">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Inspection.Article, new { @class = "col-form-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Inspection.ArticleId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Inspection.Article.AddressId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Inspection.Article.ArticlePropertiesVersion.Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsCreatedOnline)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuestionaireId);
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <div class="form-group row" id="article" style="@(Model.Inspection.Article != null ? "" : "display: none")">
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <div>
                                        <span class="help-block" id="internNr">@(Model.Inspection.Article != null && !Model.Inspection.Article.InternNr.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? $"{ACA.Translations.Article.InternNr}: {Model.Inspection.Article.InternNr}" : "")</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span class="help-block" id="serialNr">@(Model.Inspection.Article != null && !Model.Inspection.Article.SerialNr.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? $"{ACA.Translations.Article.SerialNr}: {Model.Inspection.Article.SerialNr}" : "")</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <span class="help-block" id="type">@(Model.Inspection.Article != null ? $"{ACA.Translations.Article.Type}: {Model.Inspection.Article.Type?.Name} - {Model.Inspection.Article.SubType?.Name}" : "")</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning editArticleButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editArticleModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Now i need to fill the data at runtime, so fetch my object from the indexedDB and fill in the object values in the view. Anyone has an idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to Razor syntax with actual model values is to load them in the controller action before you load the view. So in order for the values to load correctly you can just do the following:

`return View(Model)`

where **Model** is the object that contains your data.

In order to fill those fields while the View has already been loaded is by doing an ajax request by Javascript to some other Action in your controller that will end with the following way:

`return JSON(Model)`

and will return your Model with its data and then load them to your Form using jQuery or anything you want.

*** EDIT ***

To accomplish this task faster than jquery you need to use js libraries that implement data-binding. Such examples are **knockout.js** and **rivets.js** depending on what fits best to your needs

Comment: I already have the `return JSON(Model)` part saved in indexeddb but how do i fill this in using jquery? i thought using `document.getelementById()` but thats just to much work.. i just wonder how to fill in this data.. The page needs to be working Offline so i can't use any controllers/ajax request..

Comment: @JelledeKeukeleire I edited my answer. Please check it again and approve it since this is what you are looking for.